# How does the number 0 look like in binary float format?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754, zero

The float format (IEEE) has 32 bits. First bit for the sign, after that 8 bits for a biased exponent and after that another 23 bits for the mantissa. In this mantissa is the first 1 (is always 1) always hidden which leads me to my question:

how does the number 0 look like in this format? because if the exponents 0 the number will always be 1.
plus the mantissa is always minimum 1 right? If they are only zeros in the mantissa it will count as '1.0'...

I really don't get this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format#Exponent_encoding) tells you:

```
0000 0000   = 0
8000 0000   = −0
```

Besides the normal float values, with exponent and mantisse there are a bunch of other irregular numbers like zero, infinity and a bunch of NaNs. There are also [subnormal numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number); where numbers below 2^-127 are approximated with fixed instead of a floating exponent.

Actually, zero is a *normal* subnormal number. Subnormals are encoded with as `(−1)signbits×2^−126 × 0.significandbits` and exponent all zero. If significantbits is zero, the result is (+/-) zero.

Comment: this means that 0 is just defined like that and there isn't an arithmetical way to get the right solution?

Comment: As you already noticed, there is no `x` for which `1.0 * 2^x` is ever zero, so no, there is no "arithmetical" way to reach 0.

Comment: As far as I can tell, Zero is a *normal* subnormal number. They are `(−1)signbits×2−126× 0.significandbits` and if significantbits is zero, the result is (+/-) zero.

Answer (score 3):

IEEE 754 binary floats with the biased exponent zero are not normalized, and there is no implicit one-bit before the binary point in the significand. Zero significand means 0.0 * 2^x, not 1.0 * 2^x.

Answer (score 2):

Zero values are represented by the **biased exponent** and **significand** both being `0`.

The sign could be `0` or `1`, representing `+0.0` and `-0.0` respectively.

For example, the negative zero looks like [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#mediaviewer/File:IEEE_754_Single_Negative_Zero.svg):

[image]