# How to add float.IsNormal to the C# Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, .net, reference, system

I have C# visual studio project .net Framework 4.8. I know that float has IsNormal() method but I can't find it.
I tried add references but it doesn't help.
How I can add IsNormal() to my project?

Comment: That method is not defined in the .Net Framework. You must target .Net 7.0

Comment: As you can see in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.single.isnormal), `float.IsNormal` is not available in .NET Framework 4.8, only in .NET Core and .NET >= 6. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575345/how-to-check-in-c-sharp-if-the-given-double-number-is-normal-i-e-is-neither-ze) discusses the same for `double`, so you might be able to adapt it for `float`

Comment: But how I can do it? My project is dll and i can't switch framework to .net or .net core

Comment: `But how I can do it?` - take [the mentioned code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26575832/11683) and adapt to float? Or take the [already adapted code](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Single.cs,202)?